# For each polygon, return yes/no value if it intersects another layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, query

I am using QGIS.

I have a polygon grid overlaying several other polygon vectors. I wish to visit each polygon in the grid and ask yes/no if each of these layers fall within the grid cell or not. I can do this easily with a spatial query to select the appropriate cells, but I want to have this information returned as a new attribute column, where each of the grid cells has a yes/no (or 1/0) value accordingly. This seems simple but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed very simple:

- Do a spatial query (with the QGIS spatial query tool) and select the intersecting features
- Open the attributetable of your polygon-layer, toggle edit mode and open the Field Calculator
- Create a new field updating only the selected features. See image below. All non intersecting features will now have NULL as default value (which you of course also can modify afterwards). Intersecting features will have the value 1
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

### Solution: General idea

In newer QGIS versions ([since QGIS 3.16](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#port-reffunctions-to-core)), you can use QGIS expressions with the [overlay functions](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=overlay_nearest#overlay-contains) to achieve this. You can decide which kind of spatial relationship you want to test for each cell: find different setting with screenshots to visually see the difference in what follows.

At the bottom, see how to automatically get the overlay condition for all (or most) layers in the project, without repeating the same expression for each individual layer manually.

### Polygons should at least partially overlap: `overlay_intersects`

Should the polygons overlap at least in part (not necessarily completely be inside) the cell, then use `overlay_intersects`. A simple expression, returning `true/false`, looks like:

```
overlay_intersects ('polygon')
```

If you apply this expression to the grid cell, it returns `true` if there is at least one feature of the layer `polygon` overlapping the current grid cell, otherwise `false`.

See this example for a more complex case with four different polygon layers combined and a `case` condition to return the color of the overlapping layer:

*The grid cells are labeled with the expression from above, returning the list of the layers that have polygons intersection with each grid cell:*
[image]

To achieve this, use this expression:

```
array_to_string (
    array_filter (
        array (
            case 
                when overlay_intersects ('poly1')
                then 'blue'
            end,
            case
                when overlay_intersects ('poly2')
                then 'red'
            end,
            case
                when overlay_intersects ('poly3')
                then 'yellow'
            end,
            case
                when overlay_intersects ('poly4')
                then 'green'
            end
        ),
        @element>0
    )
)
```

### Only list polygons completely inside the cell: `overlay_contains`

This is the result when you change `overlay_intersects` with `overlay_contains`:

[image]

### List polygons that do not touch grid cell: `overlay_disjoint`

Using `overlay_disjoint`, this is the result:

[image]

### A grid cell is completely covered by a polygon: `overlay_within`

Using `overlay_within` only turns true if the current grid cell is completely covered by a polygon as you can see in case of the green polygon at the bottom left:

[image]

### Other `overalay` functions

There are totally 8 overlay-functions. Apart from the four presented above, the remaining 4 have the following result in this case:

- `overlay_crosses`, `overlay_equals` and `overlay_touches` will all result in empty outputs (no cell will be labeled).
- Using `overlay_nearest`, however, each cell will return all layers, return a label `blue,red,yellow,green`.

Here, for a meaningful use, you should modify the arguments like set a filter condition, limit the number of matching features or set a mamimum distance. The help in the expression string builder is quite helpful in this respect.

### How to automatize the overlay of many different layers

If you have a lot of different layers, repeating the same `case ... when ... then ... end` part in the expression for each layer individually and manually can get quite cumbersome. In this case, get an array of all layers in the project, filter out the one(s) you want to skip (here: 'Grid') and then automatically repeat the expression for all the remaining layers.

The achieve this, use this expression:

```
array_to_string (
    array_foreach (
        array_filter (
            array_foreach (
                @layers ,
                layer_property( 
                    @element,
                    'name'
                )
            ),
            @element<>'Grid'
        ),
        array_to_string (
            array_filter (
                array (
                    case 
                        when overlay_intersects (@element)
                        then @element
                    end
                ),
                @element>0
            )
        )
    )
)
```

*The part of the expression outlined in red generates the array of all map layer names (the lines before and after filter out the 'Grid' layer). Each layer name is then refered by with `@element` in the `case` condition:*
[image]